# Formation of Life on various planets

Tags: biology, exoplanets

Is there any theory that suggests every creature (including bacteria and fungi) in our planet is formed by the atoms of our planet. If that is true, then is it possible that any other organisms will take form on another planet and evolute accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, every creature is composed of atoms, the same which composes whole Earth planet and it's contents. In addition to that, atoms up to iron in periodic table were formed in a cores of stars as nuclear reaction side products, which were scattered across space in a super-nova explosions. Atoms heavier than iron were formed in other processes, such as neutron star collisions and etc. That's why we (all creatures) are sometimes called simply "star dust". We are remnants of dead stars.

Planet formation process is pretty much known and must be usual across all universe. I believe that life formation in Earth is not unique at all. It must also follow some rules. Given that some exo-planet has same starting conditions as were in a primordial Earth, it's natural to expect life emergence and evolution like in Earth. However, **an exact** evolution path on exoplanet can be somewhat different than that on Earth, because evolution is a sporadic process. We don't even have guarantee that if we would rollback time and could repeat whole life evolution cycle on Earth - would have finally produced same humans as we do look now. Maybe we would look similar or maybe evolved intelligent creature would have another ancestors than that of apes.

For, example Dinosaurs were somewhat very evolved creatures and adapted to their environment as best as they can. Some interesting facts about most best killer [Tyrannosaurus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tyrannosaurus) :

- It had a binocular range of 55 degrees, surpassing that of modern hawks
- Had 13 times the visual acuity of a human
- Could see an objects moving at a **6 km** distance ! (A limiting far point)

Another Dyno - [Stenonychosaurus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stenonychosaurus), had biggest brain among Dinosaurs at that time (it could be called "genius" of Dinosaurs). It's been calculated that it had cerebrum to brain volume ratio between 31.5% and 63% percents.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, all living things on Earth are made of atoms and there is no reason why the same kinds of atoms on other planets could not form life there. However, we do not yet have any evidence that this has happened.